# Get a list of all the modules in code base

Tags: 7

This is more of a developer question.

I need a list of all the modules that are present in my code base. I am not looking for enabled or install modules. I am just looking for all the modules(code) present in my code base.

Comment: Might be out of scope and closed but just thought of sharing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command in the terminal at the root of your site.

```
grep -hr '^name =.*' . | sort
```

This is the non drush way and also helps me identify the duplicate code for a single module if any.

Comment: This gives me duplicated results. Any idea why?

Comment: Use grep -r '^name =.*' . | sort
This will give you the location of the modules as well. So that you can where your duplicate code is present.

Comment: Ah, that's what I guessed, it's the svn folder ;)